# In Linux, how do I strip all the high bits from an ascii file but keep the rest of the bits? - Like ISTRIP but with files

Tags: linux, macos, shell

I have some old wordstar files I want to be able to read, I don't care about formatting but I want the ascii.  Wordstar had the nasty habit of setting the high bit to mean certain things (end of a text word) and really using only the bottom 7 bits for character representation.

I know I could write a program to do this, but can't the shell do this with tr or sed or something.

Also there is an ISTRIP property on communication devices that does this but I don't know how to apply it to a file.

I want to read a character, do a logical and with \o177 on the value of the character, and then write out the character.

Comment: See [How to Convert WordStar Files to Plain Text and Microsoft Word](http://ataridogdaze.com/tech/wordstar-convert.html) for a short *Perl* script that does the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `tr` can do this:

```
LC_ALL=C tr '\200-\377' '\000-\177'
```

Here's an example:

```
$ printf '\xE8\xE5\xEC\xEC\xEF world' | LC_ALL=C tr '\200-\377' '\000-\177'
hello world
```

Comment: That looks good, however when it encounters the first character with a high bit set it ends with tr: Illegal byte sequence.  I think maybe I need to put \o200